# In Python, how would I do this Datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

```
right_now = datetime.datetime.now()
one_hour_before = ?????
```

How can I use right_now to get one_hour_before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
right_now = datetime.datetime.now()
one_hour_before = right_now - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) like so:

```
right_now = datetime.datetime.now()
one_hour_before = right_now - datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
```